# Javascript "mouseover" not fired if button is down (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, mouseover

I have a "mouseover" event on some input-fields. This event is *not* fired on Firefox if a mouse button is down. Is it a bug? (I'm using Firefox 50.1.0).

```js
$(function() {
    $('#container').on('mouseover','.myclass', tdMouseover);     
});
    
    
function tdMouseover(e) {
    console.log("mouseover");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <input id='editableDiv1' class="myclass"></input>
  <input id='editableDiv2' class="myclass"></input>
  <input id='editableDiv3' class="myclass"></input>
  <input id='editableDiv4' class="myclass"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is suggested here
[Firefox: mouseover doesn't work while mouse button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221699/firefox-mouseover-doesnt-work-while-mouse-button-is-pressed)

> It is not working in Firefox because the textbox is being 'dragged' in the browser, like how you can highlight text and drag and drop it into another text field.
>
> You can disable this functionality with css: **user-drag: none**; and **user-select: none**; which fixes your problem.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#container').on('mouseover','.myclass', tdMouseover);     
});
    
    
function tdMouseover(e) {
    console.log("mouseover");
}
```

```css
input{
  user-drag: none; 
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <input id='editableDiv1' class="myclass"></input>
  <input id='editableDiv2' class="myclass"></input>
  <input id='editableDiv3' class="myclass"></input>
  <input id='editableDiv4' class="myclass"></input>
</div>
```